# Existence of convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

IF $U=\{u\in R^n : ||u||\leq 1\}$, how do I know that there exists a sequence $\{u_k\}$ such that $\lim u_k=0$?

Comment: $u_k = \vec{0} ~\forall~ k$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :/

Comment: Since $U$ is set of ALL vectors $u$ such that $||u||\leq 1$, I can pick some sequence $\{u_k\}$ such that $\lim u_k=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $u_{k} = 0 \quad \forall\; k$.